# p on after img. But why margin-left doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

[image: p on after img. But why margin-left doesn't work?]

I wrote `display:block` and `float:left` for img. `margin-left` for p. All in div. Why p on img?

```css
* {
            box-sizing: border-box;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        img {
            display: block;
        }

        body {
            background-color: midnightblue;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            color: white;
        }

        .img2 {
            width: 200px;
            float: left;
        }

        .content p {
            margin-left: 30px;
        }
```

```html
<div class="content">
        <div>
            <img class="img2" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRw7Pnm4-SCq3puS-je9jG5AwQSF77oPe_ORrg7ot0gq9QDPQPt" alt="Rasm topilmadi">
        </div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetur
            adipisicing elit.
            Omnis asperiores hic
            voluptatum labore optio nobis
            accusantium vitae. Non, a! Enim error facilis a. Nam quibusdam qui excepturi facere consequatur
            voluptatibus.</p>
    </div>
```

Why `margin-left` doesn't work?
[codepen](https://codepen.io/shahriyor-ochilov/pen/wvvMQdK?editors=1100#0) for my problem

Comment: in your case, you better add margin-right:30px to your image to avoid to deal with the float behavior. (floating image overflowing a div and then the p coming next...)

Comment: thank you everyone

Comment: too bad no one answer's  told you why it did not work like you expected, you can read : https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/  and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how float left should work.
If you set **margin-left** to **220px** you will see that there is a margin for for your p-tag. I guess you want to add a margin(-right) to the img-tag instead.

Note that adding `float: left;` to the p-tag will also solve your issue, since all child nodes containing `float: left;` are just stacked from left to right inside your div element.

Answer (score 0):

The p element is `display : block` and full width (100% of viewport) now, you should change it to `width : calc(100% - [width of image])` and also `float : left` to show next to the img, now you could use `padding-left : 30px` for your p

```
<img class="img2" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRw7Pnm4-SCq3puS-je9jG5AwQSF77oPe_ORrg7ot0gq9QDPQPt" alt="Rasm topilmadi">

<p style="float: left;width: calc(100% - 200px);padding-left: 30px;"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet....</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your code, I hope you find it useful.

```css
* {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

/*img {display: block;}*/

body {
 background-color: midnightblue;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: white;
}

.content {
 width: 100%; /* The width you want */
 overflow: hidden;
}

.content .image {
 width: 100%; /* The width you want */
 overflow: hidden;
 display: block;
}

.content .image img {
 width: 200px;
 float: left;
}

.content .image p {
 /* 100% - the width of the image and margin-left */
 width: calc(100% - 230px);
 float: left;
 margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
 <div class="image">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRw7Pnm4-SCq3puS-je9jG5AwQSF77oPe_ORrg7ot0gq9QDPQPt" alt="Rasm topilmadi">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis consequuntur, maiores consequatur at nihil laborum doloremque cupiditate, quis quae quisquam, facere totam possimus praesentium aspernatur sequi nobis delectus quod iste.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

**Or ...** You can do this with the "Flex" columns

```css
* {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

/*img {display: block;}*/

body {
 background-color: midnightblue;
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: white;
}

.image {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 width: 100%;
}

.column {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 flex-basis: 100%;
 flex: 1;
}
.column img {max-width: 100%;}
.column.big {
 flex: 2;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
 <div class="column">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRw7Pnm4-SCq3puS-je9jG5AwQSF77oPe_ORrg7ot0gq9QDPQPt" alt="Rasm topilmadi">
 </div>
 <div class="column big">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione repellat beatae dolore repellendus sunt magnam, eligendi neque sed! A, nam, facere. Eaque architecto consectetur fuga, ut fugit nesciunt! Culpa, laboriosam.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "margin-right:30px" to your image instead of adding "margin-left:30px" to your p tag

```
.img2 {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  margin-right:30px;
}
```